# Enabling all users to access Zeppelin notebooks via IP address

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I have followed all the steps in the [documentation](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.0/install/install.html) to install Zeppelin.

I have created a notebook which I wish to share with the team. 
I have only shared the url for the notebook : http://172.11.2.33:8080/#/notebook/2ESDVJJEX

But, my team-members are not able to access the notebook.

My machine is reachable via ping to other users. Only Zeppelin is not.

```
$ ping 172.11.2.33 
PING 172.11.2.33 (172.11.2.33) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.11.2.33: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=119 ms
```

I have configured shiro.ini file to enable access via [login credentials](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0/setup/security/shiro_authentication.html#security-setup)

If I try to reach the machine, it says:

```
This site can’t be reached 172.11.2.33 refused to connect.
Search Google for 192 168 100 165 8080
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Comment: Does your zeppelin run on your computer (i.e. not a server)?

Comment: Yes. I plan to deploy zeppelin to a server later on though

Comment: Maybe your operating system or network architecture is denying such requests. You should talk to your network administrator.

Answer (score 2):

Zeppelin defaults to listen only locally.

Update / set `zeppelin.server.addr` to `0.0.0.0` in the XML config

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem that Zeppelin is properly parsing the `*` that is set in the site config. I worked around this problem by using `*:*`

In order to allow remote connections to the site that Zeppelin serves do the following:

Copy or rename the `conf/zeppelin-site.xml.template` file to `conf/zeppelin-site.xml`

Modify the `zeppelin.server.allowed.origins` to be like so

```
<property>
  <name>zeppelin.server.allowed.origins</name>
  <value>*:*</value>
  <description>Allowed sources for REST and WebSocket requests (i.e. http://onehost:8080,http://otherhost.com). If you leave * you are vulnerable to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-173</description>
</property>
```

Restart Zeppelin